# Populating a input checkbox with the result of an Ajax call

Tags: jquery

I need to set the value of a Bootstrap checkbox based on the value returned be an Ajax call.

My checkbox code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="EditDisplayOneLineText" id="EditDisplayOneLineText"value=""  class="btn btn-xs" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="default">
```

My jQuery:

```
var dt = result[22];
if (dt == 1) {
  $('#EditDisplayOneLineText').is(':checked');
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should be setting the checked [property](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to true like:

```
$('#EditDisplayOneLineText').prop('checked', true);
```

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the **checked property of a checkbox**.

Comment: @08691 Ha and thanks for your reply. I did try this but if the returned value is 0, it dos not change the state of the checkbox toggle, any ideas?

Comment: Yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/awjhu76o/. If it doesn't for you there must be an underlying issue. Check the console for errors

Comment: @DCJones In your comment you said "if the returned value is 0" but your code only checks for `if (dt == 1)`. And as you can see by Rory's fiddle, the code is solid.

Comment: j08691 Hi, if I remove all the references to Bootstrap data-toggle and just have it as a normal checkbox, it works. But my aim was to have a checkbox toggle switch which is ON if (dt == 1) and OFF if if (dt !=1).